# Why controller spec is fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I write a spec for the controller action `create` and when I running test, shell show me an error

```
   expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
```

there is spec

```
let(:valid_attributes) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:company) }

describe 'with valid params' do
  it 'creates a new company' do
    expect { post :create, company: valid_attributes }.to change(Company, :count).by(1)
```

and there is factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :company do
    title Faker::Company.name
    url Faker::Internet.domain_word
    image File.open(File.join(Rails.root, '/spec/fixtures/POEox311zoM.jpg'))
  end
end
```

how fix? I don't know what did i do wrong

***upd***

```
  def create
    @company = Company.new(company_params)
    if @company.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

Comment: Without the code of the controller (it is a controller under test?), it can be anything.

Comment: sorry, I update a question

Comment: Please post your :company_params hash.

Comment: If saving the new company is all the same to you, you can skip the if-else block. But this is where the problem lies, probably. Find out, if @company.save is true, or false.

Comment: replace `@company.save` with `@company.save!` (for testing) so that it throws an error and you would know what is wrong, probably a validation error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between `@object.save` and `@object.save!` is that the first fails softly by returning false, and this is why we do `if @object.save` because if would return `true` if saved and `false` otherwise. The second (the bang`!` method) throws an error, which is more sutable for conditions where you don't check the return value, or maybe a rake task.

Also for your controller you should handle failing saves rather than just redirect, for example:

```
def create
  @company = Company.new(company_params)
  if @company.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

This way the failing object is carried along to the `:new` template, and then there you could handle those errors, with something like this

```
<% if @company.errors %>
  <% @company.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <div class='error'><%= message %></div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This way the template will show the error